# Bash redirection stops working ( using "set -x" debug outputs )

Tags: bash, find, io-redirection, xargs

My *main* script starts like this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -x #Debug avec des stacktrace partout
set -u #Erreur si variable non définie

export >$REP_FRONTAL/env.bash

TRACE=$REP_FRONTAL/traces.log
exec >$TRACE 2>&1

source $REP_FRONTAL/lib.sh
```

Where REP_FRONTAL is an environment variable. It contains the path where *main* and *lib.sh* both are.

I can see that all outputs, including debugging (set -x) are redirected to file trace.log

But I have a line of code which breaks this behavior. I used to call it from a function defined in a sourced *lib.sh* file, but I have also tried to put it somewhere directly in the file : this line always seems to break the behavior of redirecting to trace.log.

Here is the line :

```
(find $REP_FRONTAL -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 -P 4 dos2unix  2>/dev/null)
```

Here is what the tail of trace.log looks like :

```
+ mkdir -p /somedir/a/b/
+ find /path/in/REP_FRONTAL/variable -type f -print0
+ xargs -0 -n 10 -P 4 dos2unix
```

And then : end of file..

Removing the redirection from the line does not help :

```
(find $REP_FRONTAL -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 -P 4 dos2unix  ) #same result with this line
```

Can you guess what's wrong here ? 
Thank you

Comment: Why do you run the `find | xargs` in a subshell with `( )`?

Comment: Seems like changing the line to (find $REP_FRONTAL -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 -P 4 dos2unix  >/dev/null 2&>1)   does the job. I guess it is because of the -0 option of xargs. Can someone explain how not to break redirection while not sending standart output to /dev/null ?

Comment: The subshell part was actually an attempt to solve my problem, I guess it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

That worked :
Don't know why but I would appreciate knowing. 
The accepted answer should go to the on who could explain.

```
find $REP_FRONTAL -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 10 -P 4 dos2unix > /dev/null 2&1
```

The parenthesis were useless, as pointed out by Jens in the comments.